# Corner rounding not visible in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to do this as first time jetpack practice
[image]

Actually this is the code, the only thing missing is the rounded corners, I tried it and it does clip content, but it is not visible.

```
@Preview
@Composable()
fun Horizontal_card (){
Row(
    Modifier
        .size(width = 352.dp, height = 80.dp)
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
    Spacer(Modifier.width(16.dp))
    Cardcontent ()
}

}
```

This is the preview of the component:
[image: image2]

Comment: You can try to set another background color(Ex: Color.DarkGray) for the Row. Don't use the same color with your Cardcontent background. And the Cardcontent should be fillMaxSize.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Order of Modifiers matter. At the moment you set your background with

```
fun Modifier.background(
    color: Color,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape
) = this.then(
    Background(
        color = color,
        shape = shape,
        inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
            name = "background"
            value = color
            properties["color"] = color
            properties["shape"] = shape
        }
    )
)
```

which uses `RectangleShape` by default.

You should either call

```
Modifier
    .size(width = 352.dp, height = 80.dp)
    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
```

or

```
Modifier
 .size(width = 352.dp, height = 80.dp)
 .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
 .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
```